# Telerik GridNumericColumn direction problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, telerik

I'm using a telerik RadGrid with direction RTL.

I have a telerik GridNumericColumn and the problem is that it shows numbers this way:

> 500-

instead of

> -500

can someone give an advice ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of the browser. Bidirectional algorithm will swap the number and the sign. 
Check this out

```
<div dir="rtl">-5</div>
```

You can change this in the markup by using bdo element with ltr direction:

```
<div dir="rtl">
 <bdo dir="ltr">-5</bdo>
</div>
```

Since Telerik set the text for the column directly in the cell, it will be easier for you to set ItemStyle.CssClass and HorizontalAlign="Right". The css class will look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myClass
    {
        direction:ltr;          
    }
</style>
<telerik:GridNumericColumn>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="myClass" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
</telerik:GridNumericColumn>
```

I have used the technique above(with the css class) in few projects and it is working fine for me.

Interesting readings on that subject:

- http://freenet-homepage.de/prilop/bidirectional-text.html
- http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/charset/text-direction.html
- http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/dirlang.html